# Quantile regression in python

Tags: python-2.7, regression, quantile, non-linear-regression, quantile-regression

I have a data set in python (python 2.7). I want to find the Quantile regression for this data set. Can anybody help me to how to solve it? Thank you. 
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.random.random(100)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, 100)
Y = X*X*X
Y = Y+noise
plt.plot(X,Y, 'o', color='black')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statsmodels library has two implementations of quantile regression. The first is by using
[statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression.QuantReg](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression.QuantReg.html)
and the other one is [statsmodels.formula.api.quant_reg](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.quantreg.html)
There is a marginal difference between the two and further reading can be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403028/python-statsmodels-difference-in-output-formula-api-vs-regression-quantile).