# python statsmodels: Difference in output "formula.api" vs. ""regression.quantile_regression"

Tags: python, api, statsmodels, quantile-regression

For the modul `statsmodels` using `python`, I would please like to know how differences in calling the same procedures using `statsmodels.formula.api` versus `statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression` come about.
In particular, I obtain differences in parameter estimates.

A minimum working example is attached.

```
#%% Moduls;
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg


#%% Load in sample data;
data = sm.datasets.engel.load_pandas().data

#%% smf-Version;
model1 = smf.quantreg(formula='foodexp ~ income', data=data, missing="drop")
result1 = model1.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)

#%% QuantReg-Version;
model2 = QuantReg \
    (
        data['foodexp'].values,
        exog            =           sm.tools.tools.add_constant(data['income']).values,
        missing         =           'drop'
    )
result2 = model2.fit \
    (
        q              =           0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06
    )

#%% Compare Results;
print(result1.params[0])
print(result2.params[0])
print('Difference times 10^9:       ' + str(abs(10**9*(result1.params[0]-result2.params[0]))))
```

EDIT:

I need to edit my question; the workaround proposed by below, for which I am still very grateful, does not work in the applied setting; reason: I do not have only 1 regressor.
Please find the modified version attached.

```
#%% Moduls;
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg


#%% Load in sample data;
data = sm.datasets.engel.load_pandas().data
data['income2'] = data['income']**2

#%% smf-Version;
model1 = smf.quantreg(formula='foodexp ~ income + income2', data=data, missing="drop")
result1 = model1.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)

#%% QuantReg-Version;
model2 = QuantReg \
    (
        data['foodexp'].values,
        exog            =           sm.tools.tools.add_constant(data[['income', 'income2']].values),
        missing         =           'drop'
    )
result2 = model2.fit \
    (
        q              =           0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06
    )

#%% Compare Results;
print(result1.params[0])
print(result2.params[0])
print('Difference times 10^9:       ' + str(abs(10**9*(result1.params[0]-result2.params[0]))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a small change in your code. That's making a big difference

```
#%% QuantReg-Version;
model2 = QuantReg ( data['foodexp'].values, exog = sm.tools.tools.add_constant(data['income'].values), missing = 'drop')
```

As you are putting it outside is making a big difference in internal implementation.

Final implementation

```
    #%% Moduls;
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
    from statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg


    #%% Load in sample data;
    data = sm.datasets.engel.load_pandas().data

    #%% smf-Version;
    model1 = smf.quantreg(formula='foodexp ~ income', data=data, missing="drop")
    result1 = model1.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', 
    max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)

    #%% QuantReg-Version;
    model2 = QuantReg \
        (
            data['foodexp'].values,
            exog  =   sm.tools.tools.add_constant(data['income'].values),
            missing  = "drop"
        )
    result2 = model2.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)

    #%% Compare Results;
    print(result1.params[0])
    print(result2.params[0])
    print('Difference times 10^9:       ' + str(abs(10**9*(result1.params[0]-result2.params[0]))))
```

Addition to my above code. I have copied exog from model 2 to model 1

```
    #%% Moduls;
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg


#%% Load in sample data;
data = sm.datasets.engel.load_pandas().data
data['income2'] = data['income']**2

model1 = smf.quantreg(formula='foodexp ~ income + income2', data=data, missing="drop")
model2 = QuantReg (data['foodexp'].values, exog = sm.tools.tools.add_constant(data[['income', 'income2']].values), missing = 'drop')
model1.exog = model2.exog 

result1 = model1.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)
result2 = model2.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)

#%% Compare Results;
print(result1.params[0])
print(result2.params[0])
print('Difference times 10^9:       ' + str(abs(10**9*(result1.params[0]-result2.params[0]))))
```

And second approach:- I have copied exog from model 1 to model 2

```
#%% Moduls;
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg


#%% Load in sample data;
data = sm.datasets.engel.load_pandas().data
data['income2'] = data['income']**2

model1 = smf.quantreg(formula='foodexp ~ income + income2', data=data, missing="drop")
model2 = QuantReg (data['foodexp'].values, exog = sm.tools.tools.add_constant(data[['income', 'income2']].values), missing = 'drop')
model2.exog = model1.exog 

result1 = model1.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)
result2 = model2.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)

#%% Compare Results;
print(result1.params[0])
print(result2.params[0])
print('Difference times 10^9:       ' + str(abs(10**9*(result1.params[0]-result2.params[0]))))
```

If i keep both exog to same values, answers are equal. So there is clear difference in implementation for data conversion i stated previously.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! Is there any easy intuition for what is happening that makes the differences, in particular, given, they are so marginal? 

Further, I edit my question, for I had made it too simple. Do you have an idea regarding this, too, please?

Comment: There is no difference in the implementation. If you go to below link you'll find that both ways create instance of this class QuantReg. Major difference between this 2 is both have different pre-processing steps for passing data. i.e. adding constant in exog which makes difference, while quantreg handles it internally. Practically there is no difference in output. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/0289d9213d7c30b267bb86f7a6745fb0f8160ddf/statsmodels/regression/quantile_regression.py

Comment: @Sinistrum Please have a look at my new observations i have added above

Comment: Thank you so much - your effort clearly shows the issue.